# Como obtener datos con una consulta MySQL de 5 tablas

Tags: mysql

Esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT 
p.nombre,
p.cedula, 
h.cod_hoja,
h.fecha_consulta,
h.hojaEvolucion,
h.planEvolucion,
d.nombre_diagnostico
FROM hoja_evolucion as h
JOIN paciente_hoja as ph
    ON h.cod_hoja = ph.cod_hojaFK
JOIN pacientes as p
ON ph.cedulaFK = p.cedula 
JOIN citas as c
 ON c.cedulaFK = p.cedula
 JOIN diagnostico as d
on c.cod_diagnosticoFK = d.cod_diagnostico
order by d.cod_diagnostico
```

Los datos que genera son erroneos, y esta es la info que deseo obtener

```
 p.nombre,
    p.cedula, 
    h.cod_hoja,
    h.fecha_consulta,
    h.hojaEvolucion,
    h.planEvolucion,
    d.nombre_diagnostico
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu query tenias campos que no quieres que aparezcan según lo indicado, tenias también demás alguna tablas de las cuales tampoco requieres información..entonces tu query debería de quedar así:

```
SELECT p.cedula, h.cod_hoja,h.fecha_consulta,h.hojaEvolucion,
h.planEvolucion,d.nombre_diagnostico
FROM  hoja_evolucion  as h
INNER JOIN pacientes as p ON ph.cedulaFK = p.cedula 
INNER JOIN diagnostico as d on c.cod_diagnosticoFK = d.cod_diagnostico
order by d.cod_diagnostico
```